# Swagger CodeGen Https SSL Connectivity

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I need to create swagger codegen client for java, javascript pointing to swagger yaml pusblished on https.

When tried below command got SSLHandshakeError.

```
"swagger-codegen generate -i https://localhost:443/api/swagger.yaml -l java -o java-api/."
```

Also when swagger codegen generates client will it have SSL Mutual TLS code for https swagger spec url?

Please help.

Answer (score 13):

Please add `-D io.swagger.parser.util.RemoteUrl.trustAll=true` when generating the code.

Ref: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/FAQ#is-there-a-way-to-disable-certificate-verification

UPDATE: On May 2018, about 50 top contributors and template creators of Swagger Codegen decided to fork Swagger Codegen to maintain a community-driven version called [OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator). Please refer to the [Q&A](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/qna.md) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

the above answer didn't work for me. if you are facing the same problem as I just use the bellow structure

(  "swagger:generate": "SET JAVA_OPTS=-Dio.swagger.parser.util.RemoteUrl.trustAll=true -Dio.swagger.v3.parser.util.RemoteUrl.trustAll=true && openapi-generator generate -i https://xxxxxx/swagger/1.0/swagger.json -g typescript-angular -o ./src/code-gen"
)
that's how I solved it